# Welcome to Dr Mayhem as Pro Tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

In the absence of an official post from SE, I'd like to announce that a new moderator is taking over for [Ben Alpert](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/23/ben-alpert):

[image: Dr Mayhem]

Dr Mayhem is already a moderator on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com) and has been one of our most involved users, currently third for rep with 12.1k, so I am confident he'll do a great job!  Thank you for contributing your time to the site.

Please see [the original Pro Tem announcement](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/150/28) for more information on Beta moderators, and [this page](https://music.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) which lists all current moderators and also links to more information about the mod selection process.

Comment: Needs more [flair](http://music.stackexchange.com/users/flair/104.png). :P Congrats Dr Mayhem!

Comment: @Luke Happy? :P

Comment: I made a very minor tweak to your post @Matthew. Very happy to help here, as security and music are my two top interests (my work and play jobs)

Comment: @DrMayhem Excellent!

Comment: Woo - 2nd!. I blame you for raising interest @Matthew :-)

Comment: @DrMayhem: Congrats! I am confident that you'll do a better job than me. :)

Comment: Ben - Thanks. you will be missed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because we are having [elections](http://music.stackexchange.com/election/1)!